# SQL: Changing numeric date to "Date"

Tags: sql, date, type-conversion, numeric, vertica

My date variables are `Numeric(37)` in the format `(20160404,20160405,...)`. Following other questions I have tried the following,

```
select convert(datetime, date_var)
```

with error `Column datetime does not exist`.

```
select convert(date, date_var)
```

same error as above.
Also tried,

```
select convert(date, convert(float, date_var))
```

with the same error.

```
select cast(convert(VARCHAR, date_var) as datetime)
```

gives a similar error Column `"VARCHAR" does not exist`

I apologize, my knowledge of SQL is just a few weeks old and if I needed to do further research before posting this question. I feel I am making some error, such as using wrong function for a wrong database. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Comment: Do it in two steps, first numeric to char, then char to date.

Comment: @jarlh I have tried that with the same error.

Comment: I tried `select  to_date(to_char(date_var), 'yyyymmdd')` and it worked.

Comment: @FightMilk Looks like you're using an Oracle database, and the statements you tried are specifically for Microsoft SQL Server. Although a lot of the SQL language is stanard between all databases using it, there are some differences. The date conversions betwene SQL/Oracle are a notorious difference in that regard.

Comment: @steenbergh You are absolutely correct. Given my amateur knowledge of all relational databases and basic SQL functions working correctly with my database I have been solely searching for my questions by "How to do `this` in SQL" and coming up with the solutions I have been trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this, I suppose:

```
WITH
input(datenum) AS (
          SELECT 20180602
UNION ALL SELECT 20180603
)   
SELECT datenum::VARCHAR(16)::DATE FROM input;
```

Output is:

```
datenum
2018-06-02
2018-06-03
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just use `cast()`:

```
select convert(date_var as datetime)
```

I'm not sure if Vertica supports the particular conversion, but this should work:

```
select convert(date_var as varchar(255))
```

`cast()` is the ANSI standard function for converting between different types.

In Vertica, you can also do:

```
select date_var::varchar(255)
```

This is a syntax inherited from Postgres.

For your actual problem, I wouldn't be surprised if you had to convert twice:

```
select (date_var::varchar(255))::datetime
```

Comment: In essence this should similar to `select cast(convert(VARCHAR, date_var) as datetime)`? I tried your answer and it's running without error but giving `NULL` for all the rows.

Comment: @FightMilk . . . Hmmm.  These constructs work in Postgres.  I would expect that if the syntax is accepted in Vertica, then it would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

it depends what you are using to run this statement. 
i guess an easy outside the box approach would be to run a script. like the one bellow.

For the conversion of numeric value to character value try the following code

```
PROC SQL;

  CREATE TABLE y AS

  SELECT PUT(x.subjid, 6.) AS subjid,

         PUT(x.date, YYMMDD10. ) AS date

  FROM x;

QUIT;
```

or if you need to do a select statement only..

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),NumberDate),112)
```

or if u need to declare a new numeric and set the date format of x

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), @x));
```